# String formatting doesn't work when running application in Android device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I have a string formatted like this.

```
<string name="instructions" formatted="true">
    Follow these instructions.
    <br/><br/>
    1. Step 1.
    <br/><br/>
    2. Step 2.
    <br/><br/>
    3. Step 3.
</string>
```

In the designer preview, it looks like this.

[image]

When I run it in an emulator or real Android device, it looks like this.

[image]

How can I get the real device to look like the designer preview?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` instead of `<br/>` like below:

```
    <string name="instructions" formatted="true">
    Follow these instructions.
    \n\n
    1. Step 1.
    \n\n
    2. Step 2.
    \n\n
    3. Step 3.
    </string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, you can try to use Html.fromHtml() which is in Android SDK. For an instance, like this: (Kotlin extension method)

```
fun String.toHtml() = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
} else {
    Html.fromHtml(this)
}
```

In strings.xml, the string looks like this:

```
<string name="instructions">Follow these instructions.<br/><br/>1. Step 1.<br/><br/>2. Step 2.<br/><br/>3. Step 3.</string>
```

**Note: I trim the spaces, you can add what you want, such as color**

**How to use it?**

In Fragment or Activity, using getString(R.string.instructions).toHtml() to get the Spanned and display it on UI.
Don't worry, Spanned extends from CharSequence.